# Sandboxing Blazor WebAssemblies in lieu of AppDomain Sandboxing

Tags: azure-functions, microservices, appdomain, blazor-webassembly

I need a way to securely load assemblies created by 3rd parties on a multi tenant server that may perform a variety of tasks.

What are my choices beyond what is listed below, and what is the most ideal?

- WebAssembly rehosting (perhaps borrow ideas from Blazor WASM Unit testing?)
- Silverlight (no.)
- AppDomain
- URL to an Azure Function app (how do function apps work? CScript might work as well)
- MicroServices (I don't know enough about this, I just need to load and run a DLL function)

Comment: None of the above. I don't think you understand what most of those things are. Silverlight is a browser plugin that was discontinued years ago. Webasm is a browser-only technology. Azure functions - that's just a remote service. And microservices are the fashionable name of services, ie the same as azure functions. In fact, people use Azure Functions or AWS Lambdas to create microservices.

Comment: A viable option is one that's missing - use containers